# How Many Princes per Tribe?

Tags: politics-government, parshat-nasso, police-authorities, princes-of-tribes

In [Numbers 7](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/e/et/et0407.htm), we are told about the special offerings the princes of the Tribes brought to the Tabernacle. This is not the only time we hear of this position. Princes are present in [Joshua 9](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/e/et/et0609.htm) also, for example.

**How many princes were there per tribe?** Was there one per tribe? Per family?

Please source you answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One per tribe, as seen in Numbers 1:4, and 1:16. See Also Hizkuni on 1:16 who says this explicitly.